# What does hedyotot mean?

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk

I was recently discussing the prohibition of studying "shitrei hedyotot" (loosely translated as secular studies). But when looking at a debate of the Rabbis in Talmud Bavli Sanhedrin 21:b-22:a the word hedyotot is there but it's referring to Samaritans, who are definitely not secular. So what does hedyotot actually mean? Is it a derogatory word?

Comment: "secular" is relative.

Comment: I wouldn't translate Shitrei as "studies". Documents seems more like it.

Comment: http://cal.huc.edu/oneentry.php?lemma=hdyw%2B%20N&cits=all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rashi (Shabbat 116b s.v. shtar hedyotot) describes it as page of [business] calculations or a letter regarding a lost item:

> שטר הדיוטות - כגון של חשבונות, או איגרות השלוחות למצא חפץ.

Elsewhere (Shabbat 149a) he describes it as business documents:

> כל הני - שמא יקרא בשטרי הדיוטות של מקח וממכר קאמר.

The Yerushalmi Megillah (3:4) apparently understood it to even include Scripture (cf. Tosefta Kifshuttah to Shabbat (13:2-3 p. 202)).

Jastrow writes that the etymology of "הדיוט" is from the Greek ἰδιώτης (person lacking professional skill, a private citizen, individual) the precursor of the English word idiot.

He defines it as:

> commoner, ignoble, ignorant

He also notes that it can refer to Samaritans (presumably in contradistinction to Pharisees).

Evidently, the term can have a range of meanings depending on context (see the Jastrow entry below for some examples.)

> [image]

([Image source](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Jastrow/))

Answer (score 4):

I always was under the impression that it means, ordinary or regular.

Like we have a Kohein Gadol, and a Kohein Hedyot.

See for example how it is translated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vK3X.png), in the Oxford Dictionary of the Jewish Religion.

Comment: *ordinary* is good but *regular* might not the best word here: there is a traditional though confusing distinction in English (from Latin) between *religious priests* and *secular priests*, with the former following a specific rule (so also called *regular*) while the latter serve the wider world